# lodash map and pick

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

given an array

```
var test = [{a:1, b:2, c:3}, {a:4, b:5, c:6}, {a:7, b:8, c:9}]
```

how do I get an array of new objects like `[{b:2, c:3}, {b:5, c:6}, {b:8, c:9}]` with lodash?

I have tried `_.map(test, _pick(???, ['b', 'c'])}`
What should I put in `???` ?

Comment: https://lodash.com/docs#map, https://lodash.com/docs#pick

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to pass function to map and with ES6 you can use arrow function like this.

```js
var test = [{a:1, b:2, c:3}, {a:4, b:5, c:6}, {a:7, b:8, c:9}]

var result = _.map(test, e => _.pick(e, ['b', 'c']))
console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 10):

It's not related to question asked, this can be easily done by ES6.

```
test.map(({ b, c }) => { 
  return { b, c }
});
```

Comment: Even shorter (in the simple cases): `test.map(({ b, c }) => ({ b, c });`

Comment: This is clean and nicer looking, but to be equivalent to the question asked, you would need to also check that test is not null or handle the error appropriately. Lodash will return an empty array is test is null.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use lodash if you don't want too, if your using babel(es6) you can use deconstruction to solve the issue

```js
var test = [{a:1, b:2, c:3}, {a:4, b:5, c:6}, {a:7, b:8, c:9}]

let newList = test.map(({b, c})=>{
 return {b,c}
});

document.body.append(JSON.stringify(newList));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
_.chain(test).map(function(e){return _.pick(e, ['b','c'])}).value();
```

Answer (score 0):

`_.partialRight()` can be used for trial of @Sean, such as `_.map(test, _pick(???, ['b', 'c']))`

```js
_.map(test, _.partialRight(_.pick, ['b', 'c']));

// result: [ { b: 2, c: 3 }, { b: 5, c: 6 }, { b: 8, c: 9 } ]
```